# How to check to use linear models for huge data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Generally, whenever we had the data when we want to use linear models we try to make numerical features to have normal distributions. And we check it with by plotting distribution or qqplot. It's the first time I am working on huge dataset which is having around 2000 columns. In which except 50 columns all others are numeric features. Now, how do I need to check for those many features whether there are having normal-distributions or not? how to get clarity whether to use logistic regression or not?

Comment: Pca, T-sne visualization or Any other Dimensionality Reduction methods can help to check linearity.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to check for normality, the predictors? Even under the strictest assumptions of linear modeling, we don't assume normal predictors. This is a common misconception.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! We typically expect answers to contain more detail than this. How does PCA check for linearity? How does t-SNE check for linearity? Further, the question asks about normality, not linearity.

Comment: Do you want to do inference or prediction? If the latter, don't use the assumptions of the former, simply cross-validate your solution.

Comment: for prediction.

Answer (score 1):

**how to get clarity on whether to use logistic regression or not?**

Linear regression is used when you've continuos response variable (like house price) and logistic regression is used when you've categorical response variable (e.g., spam or not spam).
There are many other techniques for both purposes.

Now, **how do I need to check for those many features whether there are having normal-distributions or not?**

Usually, when prediction accuracy is the objective, some (not all) assumptions of OLS can be safely ignored.
By the way, OLS never assumes normally distributed predictors or response variable. It assumes normality of residuals.
If your objective is to make inference, then you can check these assumptions (including normality of residuals) either by using statistical tests or diagnostic plots.
If you're using R for the same, you can simply get model diagnostic plots using plot(model) function.

Let me know, if you've any further query.